# Перемещение файла в другой каталог

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! По адресу `http://test.ru/image/tmp/152178.avatar-100x100.png` находится файл, который надо перенести в каталог, чтобы конечный путь был `http://test.ru/image/avatar/152178.avatar-100x100.png`. Пробовал делать так,

```
rename("http://test.ru/image/tmp/152178.avatar-100x100.png", "http://test.ru/image/avatar/152178.avatar-100x100.png")
```

но к сожаление возвращает `false`. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Работа с файлами происходит на стороне сервера, соответственно нужно указывать серверный путь к файлам, а не url.

```
rename( $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/image/tmp/152178.avatar-100x100.png", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/image/avatar/152178.avatar-100x100.png")
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!)

Comment: Еще такой вопрос, если в каталоге уже есть файл с таким именем то `rename` просто перезапишет этот файл (т.е. будет новый файл со старым именем)?

Comment: @r.mcreal да, об этом явно написано в документации к этой функции